# How can I view the links in the profile description of a user without the required 10 reputation?

Tags: support, profile-page, hyperlinks, account-suspension

When a user gets suspended, their reputation drops to 1, which means that the links in their profile description can't be viewed by the readers.  Example:

- [profile description before account suspension](https://web.archive.org/web/20140707165745/https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/15479/val)
- [profile description after account suspension](https://web.archive.org/web/20150317092917/https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/15479/val)

How can I view the links in the profile description of a suspended user in the event web.archive.org or some other mirrors didn't copy the webpage prior to the account suspension?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the Stack Exchange API. I see that you're currently suspended on Web Applications but [this call](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users-by-ids#order=desc&sort=reputation&ids=18147&filter=!9Qz3XXmbb&site=webapps&run=true)
returns

```
"about_me": "<p><a href=\"https://stackexchange.com/users/169656/franck-dernoncourt\"><img src=\"https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/169656.png\" width=\"208\" height=\"58\" alt=\"profile for Franck Dernoncourt on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&amp;A sites\" title=\"profile for Franck Dernoncourt on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&amp;A sites\" /></a></p>\n<p>FYI: <a href=\"https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/125068/synthetic-biology?referrer=NDYxODU1YzYyNmMwZWMxN2Y5Njg5M2QyMTMyNTkyZDQ2ZDVhMDBlOTE3MjkzMzViYmE2MGU0OTMxZjEwNWY1Zf4eg2C3B5lrG-c-STIfWMrpiqxxY_CdohRA4HRTTsRI0\">Synthetic Biology proposal</a>.</p>\n"
```

with working links to your flair and an Area 51 proposal. Alternatively, use the [Stack Exchange Android](https://archive.org/details/stack-exchange-apk) or iOS app (if you still have it on your smartphone, the apps have been delisted from the stores). They use the same API and don't remove the links the way the websites do.